Android: what does the log message "<timestamp> InputMethodManager invalidateInput" indicate?
When I execute a newly developed Android application (compileSdk/targetApi="33") during initialization and first screen build-up (and also later during subsequent screen refreshes) I am getting literally hundreds of informational messages:
<timestamp> InputMethodManager    I  invalidateInput
Interspersed with the above messages (every 10-15th line) is a debug  message:
<timestamp> AnimatorSet           D  mReversing is false. Don't call initChildren.
These messages appear only when I execute the application on my physical mobile (Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra / Android v14). They do not show up when running it in Android Studio's device emulator.
What do these messages try to convey to me? Are they indicating something being done false or at least suboptimal in the application?
Can I somehow get rid of them? I mean not filtering it in the Logcat (that I know how to do) but actually avoiding it being emitted, so that this doesn't appear in the first place.
